# Use DataAdapter results as String for new Query

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am in the process of creating a "Related Items" feature for an online store. I have a SQL query that will pull a list of ITEMs from a Database and display them on the page but I'm trying to rig up system where the list will change depending on a few variables.

The code is below and the part I'm having trouble with is getting a usable string out of Query1 to be used as the 'results' variale in query 2.

```
Public Shared Function GetExtraProducts(ByVal strAddOnCat As String) As DataSet
    Dim connect As New SqlConnection

    Dim Data1 As New DataSet
    Dim data2 As New DataSet
    connect.ConnectionString = "SERVER = SERVER-SQL01; Trusted_Connection=yes; DATABASE=GlobalPCSQL"
    connect.Open()

    Dim query1 As String = ""
    Dim query2 As String = ""
    query1 = "SELECT StockID FROM dbo.ADDONLISTS WHERE SubCategory = 'Acer-Desktops'"

    Dim command1 = New SqlDataAdapter(query1, connect)
    command1.Fill(Data1)

    If Data1.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        query1 = "SELECT StockID FROM dbo.ADDONLISTS WHERE SubCategory = 'Generic'"
        Dim command3 = New SqlDataAdapter(query1, connect)
        command3.Fill(Data1, "StockID")
    End If

    Dim results As String = ""
    For Each row In Data1.Tables(0).Rows

        results += row.ToString() + "','"
    Next
    If results.Length > 2 Then
        results = results.Substring(0, results.Length - 2)
    End If




    'results = "'HD12047' , 'TV12008'"

    query2 = "SELECT stock_items.Stockcode, STOCK_GROUPS.XW_URL as stockgroup, STOCK_GROUP2S.XW_URL as stockgroup2, STOCK_MAINGROUP.XW_URL as stockmaingroup, stock_items.Stockcode as pID, stock_items.description as pName, stock_web.sales_html as pdescription, stock_web.picture_url as pImage, stock_web.picture_url as pLargeimage, stock_items.sellprice1 as pPrice, stock_items.SELLPRICE1, stock_items.SELLPRICE2, stock_items.SELLPRICE3, stock_items.SELLPRICE4, stock_items.SELLPRICE5, stock_items.SELLPRICE6, stock_items.SELLPRICE7, stock_items.SELLPRICE8, stock_items.SELLPRICE9, stock_items.status as itemtype, stock_items.SELLPRICE10 as pListPrice, stock_items.x_totalstock as pInStock, stock_items.x_webhits as pHits, stock_items.ISACTIVE, stock_items.WEB_SHOW, stock_items.X_WebBlub as X_WebBlurb, stock_items.x_webpromo as X_PROMOPAGE, stock_items.last_updated as lastupdated, stock_items.x_stockleveloverride, isnull(stock_items.Restricted_item,'N') as Restricted_item "
    query2 += "FROM stock_items Left OUTER Join STOCK_WEB ON (stock_items.Stockcode = STOCK_WEB.Stockcode) LEFT OUTER JOIN STOCK_GROUPS ON (STOCK_GROUPS.GROUPNO = STOCK_ITEMS.STOCKGROUP) LEFT OUTER JOIN STOCK_GROUP2S ON (STOCK_GROUP2S.GROUPNO = STOCK_ITEMS.STOCKGROUP2) LEFT OUTER JOIN STOCK_MAINGROUP ON (STOCK_MAINGROUP.GROUPNO = STOCK_GROUPS.XW_MAINGROUP)"
    query2 += "WHERE stock_items.ISACTIVE='Y'  AND stock_web.picture_url IS NOT NULL "
    query2 += "AND stock_items.Stockcode IN ('" + results + "')"


    query2 += results


    Dim command2 = New SqlDataAdapter(query2, connect)
    command2.Fill(data2)
    connect.Close()


    Return data2

End Function
```

Everything works fine if I spoon feed the stock Id numbers into query 2 (in place of the ' + results + ' section, but when I try to use the string from query one all I get is

```
Incorrect syntax near 'System.Data.DataRow'
```

Which makes me think that even if I got the syntax sorted, it'l only search for System.Data.Datarow instead of the actual value of the field.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `DataRow` can contain many `DataColumn`s. Even though your return `DataRow` contains only one `DataColumn`, you must still specify the `DataColumn`:

```
Dim results As String = ""
For Each row In Data1.Tables(0).Rows

    results += row.Item(0).ToString() + "','" '<--- Added Item(0)'
Next
If results.Length > 2 Then
    results = results.Substring(0, results.Length - 2)
End If
```

Also, double-check that you have an apostrophe for the first result. You might need:

```
Dim results As String = "'"
```

Finally, on an unrelated note, while the `+` operator can be used for string concatenation, I would recommend you use the `&` operator instead and only use `+` for numerical addition:

```
results &= row.Item(0).ToString() & "','" '<--- Added Item(0)'
```

Comment: You're a gentleman and a scholar. I know that's right because now all the syntax errors say "Incorrect syntax near [random stock code] whereas before it just said I was dumb.

Comment: These apostrophe's will drive me mad. Everytime I add or remove one I get   syntax errors or unclosed quotation errors. Still, the string is working! Thanks heaps.

Comment: Nevermind, it's all working, apostrophe's and all. Thanks heaps!